# Copying (scp/sshfs) is far slower than iperf3 would suggest

Tags: networking, performance, scp

I've got a ~160MB directory with 742 files. Copying it with `cp` over `sshfs` and with `scp` takes roughly 50 seconds (**either way**).

However, iperf reports the following:

```
Accepted connection from 83.10.32.103, port 55218
[  5] local 161.35.220.161 port 5201 connected to 83.10.32.103 port 55220
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  22.8 MBytes   192 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  27.4 MBytes   230 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  28.9 MBytes   242 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  26.4 MBytes   221 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  26.6 MBytes   223 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  28.2 MBytes   237 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  27.2 MBytes   228 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  29.1 MBytes   244 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  30.0 MBytes   252 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  30.0 MBytes   252 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]  10.00-10.03  sec   790 KBytes   237 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-10.03  sec   278 MBytes   232 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

As far as I understand, the network is the slowest component here, but it still runs at ~25MB/s. Therefore, copying the directory should take around 6-7 seconds. In reality, it takes around 50s.

What is the source of this difference?

Comment: I suspect it's the overhead of opening 742 files for reading at this end, and the overhead of opening 742 files for writing at the other end. Read `man tar` and consider packing the files into a single archive (optionally with compression) and transfer the archive.

Comment: @waltinator You're correct, transferring a `.tar` takes around 7 seconds. I don't think it's just opening files though. `tar`'ing (which also opens all these files) on the remote takes a few seconds, and some negligible time on my local machine, so it still doesn't add up.

Comment: not the filesystem overhead but the networking overhead: scp basically does a whole new transaction per file

Comment: The largest block of time would be creating the files on the target filesystem - especially if the disk is severly fragmented.